# If not passed a variable, use DB default (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a function that is inserting a record into my DB (MySQL). It has many columns, many of which have default values in the DB. Passing in values for these variables is therefore optional.

```
def assign_X_to_Y( options = {} )
 . . . 
 @bar.var1 = options[:foo]
 . . .
end
```

I would like to do the following:

-If a variable exists (ex: options[:foo]), add it to the record I'm making.

```
@bar.var1 = options[:foo]
```

-If it doesn't, I don't want to add it--I want to use the DB default.

I know I can simply do an `if`:

```
if options[:foo]
   @bar.var1 = options[:foo]
end
```

But I have a lot of these variables and so I think there must be a nicer way that having loads of if-statements. Something like the "if doesn't exist set to null" expression:

```
@bar.var1 = options[:foo] || nil
```

Is there anything like what I am saying? I can't use the above expression because I don't want to set it to null (which I think it would do), I want to use the default value…

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you assigning the values to a model or creating a SQL statement? Please add the `assign_X_to_Y`  method to your question. Its impossible to give refactoring advice about an method which is not even shared with the reader.

Comment: Added `@bar.var1 = options[:foo]` to the method…does that clarify that I am adding values to a model?

Comment: Yeah, if its a model just do `@bar.assign_attributes(options)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `@bar` is an model you can simply pass a hash:

```
Bar.create(hash) # creates a Bar with the defaults from your schema
@bar.assign_attributes(hash)
@bar.update(hash) # same as object but commits the changes to the db
```

If bar is a Plain Old Ruby class you can give it the same functionality by:

```
class Bar

  attr_accessor :foo
  attr_accessor :baz
  attr_accessor :woggle

  def initialize(hash)
     assign_values(hash)
  end

  def assign_attributes(hash)
    assign_values(hash)
  end 

  private 

  def assign_values(hash)
    hash.each do |k,v|
      send "#{k}=", v
    end
  end
end
```

Then I can simply create an object with:

```
Bar.new(foo: 1, baz: 3)
```

Note that this will respect object encapsulation - if I try to do:

```
Bar.new(haxxored: true)
```

It will raise a `NoMethodError`. Just like `@bar.haxxored = true`.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, the best way to handle this would be to use the `public_send` method in Ruby:

```
def set_new_property(obj, prop_name, prop_value)
  obj.class.__send__(attr_accessor: "#{prop_name}")
  obj.public_send("#{prop_name}=", prop_value)
end
```

Bear in mind that you'll have to set explicit attribute accessors for each potential property being assigned.

Comment: Or you could just do [instance_variable_set](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/instance_variable_set) if you are going to trump encapsulation anyways.